# Mongodb interface for high speed updates

Tags: database, mongodb

Are there any examples with source code for high speed (at least 10,000 read/write of record/s) mongodb read/update of a single record at a time ?
Alternatively where could I look in the mongodb server code for a way to say inject a customised put/get record for example with the “wired tiger” storage system ?
For example say that mongo C interface is similar to oracle's sql*net client, I'd need something similar to sqlldr bulk insert/update tool.
Thank you for any hint where to start from.

Comment: It's not quite clear what you are asking, but the source code of the database is here https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/tree/master/src/mongo/db. WiredTiger is a separate project https://github.com/wiredtiger/wiredtiger.  Mongo "interface" is  fundamentally different to any sql client. Mongo "client" is much thicker.  The "bulk loader" https://docs.mongodb.com/database-tools/mongoimport/ is just a CLI written in Go which uses standard driver https://docs.mongodb.com/drivers/

Answer (score 0):

Raw performance is highly dependent on hardware. If the only requirement is "10,000 reads/writes of one document per second", then all of the following would help:

- Having an empty database.
- Storing the database in memory (tmpfs).
- Using linux rather than windows.
- Using a CPU with high clock speed, at the expense of core count.
- Using the fastest memory available.

You might notice that some of these conditions are mutually exclusive with many practical systems. For example, if you truly have an empty database or nearly-empty database that fits in memory, you could probably use something like redis instead which is much simpler (i.e. has WAY less functionality) and thus for a simple operation like read/write of a simple document would be way faster.

If you try to implement this requirement on a real database, things become way more complicated. For example, "10,000 reads/writes of one document which is part of a 10 GB collection which is also being used in various aggregation pipelines" is a very different problem to solve.

For a real-world deployment there are simply too many variables to account for, you need to look at your system and go through performance investigation or hire a consultant who can do this. For example, if you talk to your database over TLS (which is very common) that creates significant overhead in the wire protocol which would absolutely seriously affect your peak r/w performance of trivial document sizes.